# Ajax response contains struts2 tags which are not translated

Tags: ajax, struts2, outputstream, ajax-request, actioncontext

I am using an ajax request that constructs a modal box on the server side. The content of the modal box will contain a "calculated" link, surrounded with a form  :

```
StringBuffer htmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();
htmlBuffer.append(
...
"<td>"+
"<s:form action='goToLocationAction' id='formId'>" +
"<s:textfield class='form-control hidden' name='mybean.beanid' value='" + getStringContent(entity.getBeanId()) + "'/>" +
"<s:a href='#' onClick='document.getElementById('formId').submit();'>" + getStringContent(entity.getBeanId()) + "</s:a>" +
"</s:form>" +
"</td>"...
);

mapper.writeValue(ServletActionContext.getResponse().getOutputStream(), htmlBuffer.toString());
```

On the client-side result page, the struts tags are not translated to HTML.

Any ideas how to do this right ?

Thank you.

Comment: ... This is not how JSP works. JSP is translated on the *server* side and the templated results are sent to the client. Just build the HTML, using JSP (there's almost never any reason to generate HTML manually), and send it. What's the issue?

Comment: when a user clicks to get the details of an entry of the result table, the application uses a webservice to grab the info and constructs the modal box filled with the data to give it back.
(The page is not refreshed)

Comment: Understood. This is not how JSP works. You cannot write JSP to the client and expect the client to know what to do with it--JSP is server-side. Either build the HTML directly (yuck) or use a JSP page. You cannot send JSP directly to the client--that's not where JSP processing happens. Like I said the first time.

Comment: Yes i see that i am writing struts content and return it as a string to the client.
I was hoping that i could use some Struts class to "parse" it to HTML as if it was a regular jsp. This way i could simply return the translated content.
So you are telling me that such class/method is not available ?
Thank you already for the explanation !

Comment: Technically it’s available. Why not just use a JSP in the first place? Then you don’t have to try to work around how things work.

Comment: too heavy changes to do, not much time, too many retroactiv tests... can you tell me more about that possibility please

Comment: No. You have a tiny chunk of JSP. Write a JSP. Hooking in to the JSP engine is container-specific, fragile, and beyond a terrible idea. Do it right.